# Convert C# API Request to PHP

Tags: c#, php

I need connect to an external API and the provider has only supplied example in C#.

Here is the C# code to generate a auth token.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
      Agent : "XXX",
      Group: "XXXXXXX"
    }";

    string publicKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    byte[] agentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    var rsa2Params = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    rsa2Params.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsa2Params);

    byte[] hashValue = rsa.Encrypt(agentBytes, true);

    string output = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

I have trued with the RSA.php class

```
$rsa = new phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
$keys = $rsa->createKey();

$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => 'XXX',
   'Group' => 'XXXXXXX'
]);

$rsa->loadKey($keys['privatekey']);

$output = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($json));
```

The output gives me a Auth Key to use in the header request.  I hope I am on the right track, I get a API response saying the "Agent not found"

Comment: It's unclear to me why, in the PHP, you are base64 encoding the output of the encrypt command. In the c# that doesn't happen, unless you missed something out. In neither case have you shown how you actually make the API call either. Since the error ultimately comes from the API it would make sense to show that part, in case there's anything missing or different at that step in the two languages

Comment: If you dont base_encode it you get an output like: https://d.pr/i/MmpXW2 I believe the c# is doing the same by this `FromBase64String `

Comment: No. **From** base 64 means convert a base64 string into something else. Whereas to encode into base64 means to convert something else into base64. In other words the two things are opposites. And also you're not even using it on an equivalent variable.

Comment: The output in your screenshot looks like binary data - i.e. lots of bytes. That would be the same as what is in the `byte[] hashValue` - which is an array of bytes

Comment: the API Request is just a simple GET reguest to /auth with Header "Authorization: Bearer <token>"   The token is the "output" from their example. If I dont encode it the API request just breaks..

Comment: Which is why I asked you to show the rest of the c# to see how the data is used in the request made from there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the C# conversion to PHP

```
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();

$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => 'XXX',
   'Group' => 'XXXXXX'
]);

$publicKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$exponent = 'AQAB';

$public = [
    'n' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger(base64_decode($publicKey), 256),
    'e' => new \phpseclib\Math\BigInteger(base64_decode($exponent), 256),
];

$rsa->loadKey($public);

$token = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($json));
```

Answer (score -2):

The PHP's example is inconsistent to me:

you have:

```
$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => 'XXX',
   'Group:' => 'XXXXXXX'
]);
```

there is colon `:` for Group but there is no colon for Agent, you probably should have a colon for both or not have it at all.

also there are in C# example multiple quotes (I don't know C#) but perhaps the right JSON for PHP would be:

```
$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => '"XXX"',
   'Group' => '"XXXXXXX"'
]);
```

or

```
$json = json_encode([
   'Agent:' => '"XXX"',
   'Group:' => '"XXXXXXX"'
]);
```

most likely working:

```
$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => 'XXX',
   'Group' => 'XXXXXXX'
]);
```

Comment: You're right about the colon but wrong about the quote marks

Comment: @ADyson got even down voted so I must be wrong even more :)

Comment: The PHP array is being encoded to json.. Not like the C# code where it is already a json object. So the colon is created by the json_encode code.

Comment: @Lee i dont get the explaining at all. In PHP example you are passing one key with colon and the other without it. json_encode has nothing to do here. it should be this way `$json = json_encode(['Agent:' => 'XXX', 'Group:' => 'XXXXXXX']);` or `json_encode(['Agent' => 'XXX', 'Group' => 'XXXXXXX']);` to be consistent. However there might be other problems as well.

Comment: I encourage people who are voting down for showing their shiny working solution :) There is no need to be so humble :)

Comment: `$json = json_encode([
   'Agent' => 'XXX',
   'Group' => 'XXXXXXX'
]);` is more likely to be correct

Comment: @ADyson It looks to me more "right" as well, but the error message seems to be related to the agent field - "Agent not found" that lacks the colon instead of "Group not found" that would suggest there could be a problem with a key followed by the colon. Let's wait for the OP's check on possible combination that works or at least  changes the error message.

Comment: @Lee Is there any change by using provided examples?

Comment: The extra colon and quote marks were wrong in my example.